# Remove event listener and reset classList toggle on resize

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove a click event listener on a certain screen size, while resizing browser.

The problem is that the code below works where I refresh the page and desired result is there. However, while resizing the browser, it stays in the state of either being clickable if under the wanted width or being non clickable over the wanted width.

```
let viewPort = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
let dropToggle = document.querySelectorAll(".someparent");
let dropMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".somechild");

for (let i = 0; i < dropToggle.length; i++) {
  dropToggle[i].addEventListener('click', function a(event) {
    if (viewPort < 786) {
      dropMenu[i].classList.toggle("drop");
      if (event.dropToggle == 2);
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
      dropToggle.removeEventListener('click', a);
      /*update*/
      dropMenu[i].classList.remove("drop");
    }
    /*update*/
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
     viewPort = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }, true);
  });
}
```

So basically, I would need the function to kick in when the browser is being resized without refreshing the page. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** updated code with partial solution.

**New problem:** The toggle classList.toggle "drop" remains open if not closed on the smaller width. Adding a classList.remove to the "drop" within the else condition does not work either, this actually removes the function entirely on resize. Is there a way to reset the classList.toggle on resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the value of `viewPort` every time you resize your window. At the moment `viewPort` is initialized when you load your page but is never reinitialized again. To do this you can add a `resize` event listener to your `window`:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  viewPort = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}, true);
```

Comment: This done the trick, placing it after the else condition, thanks! However, I encountered another problem; If I click to leave it open from the smaller size, then resize to the larger width it stays open. So I tried adding: dropMenu[i].classList.remove("drop"); within the else condition but doesn't work and it removes the function on resize all together. Any ideas on how I can improve on this?

Comment: @thx1138 I would have thought that would work, so it seems strange that it doesn't/ Can you maybe edit your question to show what you tried to do to close the menu

Comment: Same here. The average user won't frantically resize the browser when visiting the site. I could leave it as is, but, it's probably not a good idea, especially for testing purposes. Also yes, the question has been updated.

Comment: @thx1138 would you be able to recreate a smaller version of your problem in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). I can help debug a little better if you do that

Comment: Sure, however I can't seem to get the function to work in jsfiddle for some reason. It's meant to hover on large screens and drop down on small. Works fine in my browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/ucojnsqp/3/

Comment: @thx1138 Hi, thanks for making the fiddle. It's a little difficult to debug the issue since the dropdown isn't appearing on the smaller screens. However, I did notice one thing you can change. Instead of adding the `window.addEventListener("resize", function() {` inside your `for` loop you should add it outside of it. If it is inside your for loop it will be added multiple times :P

Comment: Sorry about that, I need to figure out why it's not working in jsfiddle. For now, yes, taking that function out of the loop has made some progress where click function remains but the item is still opened on resize. I'll try the other solutions and will post the code that works, thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your event listener call outside of your for loop
& pass the callback as a reference in add/remove event listener method.

Also you need to add window.resize event listener (As shown below)

This code should work fine for you

```
let dropToggle = document.querySelectorAll(".someparent");
let dropMenu = document.querySelectorAll(".somechild");

function a(event) {
    dropMenu[i].classList.toggle("drop");
    if (event.dropToggle == 2);
    event.stopPropagation();
}

for (let i = 0; i < dropToggle.length; i++) {
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        viewPort = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (viewPort < 786) {
            dropToggle[i].addEventListener("click", a);
        } else {
            dropToggle[i].removeEventListener("click", a);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Matchmedia can handle this - and allow javascript functions when the media (window) matches the criteria.

References can be found here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) and here (https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/)

Effectively its media queries for javascript. And the syntax is essentially the same as for CSS media queries.

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
  const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    // do what you want when  window width is at least 768px
  } else {
    // do what you want when window width is less than 768px
  }
}
```